# Mathematical Math History books?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, math-history, book-recommendation

I'd like to compile a list of books that aren't only good books on the history of mathematics—but books that are themselves mathematical explanations. For example, imagine a biography on Cantor. This biography would be a good historical book—but *also* provide (maybe even walk-through) all of the relevant Cantor proofs. It'd teach you both history and mathematics.

Unfortunately, I don't have any ideas. My experience with mathbooks is strictly textbooks with, at best, a "Did You Know It?" esque insert at the top of a page or something.

My targets are any and all topics, honestly.

Comment: Have you looked at Mathematics and Its History by Stillwell?

Comment: Gindikin's "Tales" come to my mind: https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387360263 / http://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/462/Tales%2520Of%2520Mathematicians%2520And%2520Physicists%2520-%2520S%2520Gindikin%2520(Springer,%25202007)%2520Ww.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below are a few books I pulled off my bookshelves just now that might qualify. I’ve grouped them into three categories.

## Math history books that include a lot of mathematical development for the reader.

[**The Historical Development of the Calculus**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387943137) by Charles Henry Edwards

[**Classical and Modern Integration Theories**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1483244733) by Ivan Nikolaevich Pesin

[**Journey Through Genius. The Great Theorems of Mathematics**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/014014739X) by William Wade Dunham

[**Euler. The Master of Us All**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883853280) by William Wade Dunham

[**Algebra in Ancient and Modern Times**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/082180989X) by Veeravalli Seshadri Varadarajan

## Specific topic books that include a lot of history.

[**A Treatise on the Binomial Theorem**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848900856) by Craig Alan Smorynski (see also Phill's answer)

[**Solving Kepler’s Equation Over Three Centuries**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0943396409) by Peter Colwell

[**Space-Filling Curves**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387942653) by Hans Sagan

[**The Ellipse. A Historical and Mathematical Journey**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470587180) by Arthur Mazer

[**Proofs of the Cantor-Bernstein Theorem**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FKTHE4A) by Arie Hinkis

## Textbooks that include a lot of history.

[**Analysis by Its History**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387770313) by Ernst Hairer and Gerhard Wanner

[**A Radical Approach to Real Analysis**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883857472) by David Marius Bressoud

[**A Radical Approach to Lebesgue’s Theory of Integration**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521711835) by David Marius Bressoud

[**Classical Algebra. Its Nature, Origins, and Uses**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470259523) by Roger Lee Cooke

Answer (score 1):

I think the books by Thomas Hawkins deserve to be mentioned:

- [Lebesgue's Theory of Integration: Its Origins and Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0828402825)
- [Emergence of the Theory of Lie Groups: An Essay in the History of Mathematics 1869–1926](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461270421)
- [The Mathematics of Frobenius in Context: A Journey Through 18th to 20th Century Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FKSXCRO)

They are not ordinary textbooks aiming to teach a mathematical subject to a beginner, but if you already know the subject a bit and want to get a deeper understanding by looking at it from the historical perspective, they are very nice.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend MVT: A Most Valuable Theorem by Craig Smorynski.  It is not only a careful comparison of proofs of the Mean Value Theorem, but it is also a history of Calculus, from the Greeks to Non--standard Analysis.