# Recommended reading for the history of algebraic curves

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I want to make an overview of how our understanding of algebraic curves have progressed through time to the present day. Are there any recommended texts that would be appropriate for this type of research?

Answer (score 2):

Try the accounts below, even if they are not specific to curves:

- [History of Algebraic Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078RSWKT4) by Dieudonné
- [The Historical Development of Algebraic Geometry](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Dieudonne.pdf) by Dieudonné
- [A History of Algebraic Geometry](http://www.robertweaston.com/wp-content/uploads/documents/presentations/History_of_Algebraic_Geometry.pdf) by Easton

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2786771/589